# synchronizing access to static hashmap while modifying entryset values in java

Tags: java, synchronization, hashmap

I have a hashmap which contain Link object as value and Integer as a key.which is getting updated after every one second and at the same time it is accessed from some other class in some different thread. I want to make hashmap inaccessible while updating Value part(Link object after api response) and make it accessable once updation is complete. what is best possible way to do this.

```
   class Link{
      int id;
      int currentBWidth;
      //getter and setter
   }

public class Cache implements Runnable {
public static HashMap<Integer, Link> linkDetailsMap;//accessed by some other class
static {
    initMap();
}

private static void initMap() {
    linkDetailsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Link>(667);//needed a hashmap
                                                    with fixed size 500


    for (int count = 0; count < 500; count++) {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.setLinkId(count);
        link.setCurrentBWidth(count);
                    linkDetailsMap.put(link.getLinkId(), link);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // making a rest appi call and modifying link CurrentBWidth in
            // linkDetailsMap
            **for(Map.Entry<Integer, Link> entry:linkDetailsMap.entrySet())
                Link link = entry.getValue();
                link.setCurrentBWidth(//some vallue);
            }**
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  ......... ///extra code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) to protect modification with the write lock and reading with the read lock. You can have many readers at the same time but only one writer. That way, readers will be blocked while the writer holds the lock.

Comment: A good answer in general but overkill for the use case here with two threads.

Comment: @TimB You're right. But I almost never hear about that nice n-readers/1-writer lock, which is really convenient ... when you know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this by synchronising on the hash map.

In both threads do

```
synchronized (linkDetailsMap) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

While one of the threads is inside that synchronized block the other cannot enter it and will wait - so anything done in there will not have any threading problems.

A good alternative would be to use `ConcurrentHashMap` to store your values, I didnt suggest it immediately though as this line here "I want to make hashmap inaccessible while updating Value part(Link object after api response)" suggests that there more be more processing to do than just the put() operation and that all that processing needs protecting.

Comment: Can he use ConcurrentHashMap? As he is not updating the hashmap

Comment: @SachinPasalkar yes, but using `synchronized` "manually" performs better as you can choose which part you want to lock, based on your a-priori knowledge of how it is used.

Comment: @Matthieu: How  "you can choose which part you want to lock" part works when you sync the map? According to my understanding it will get lock on whole map

Comment: It will get a lock on the whole map, but that may be what he needs. I've added a comment on this to my answer.

Comment: @SachinPasalkar that's the point: you choose *when* you want to use `synchronized` because you *know* you may have concurrent access on your map. The `Do stuff here` pointed by TimB is where you put the code that might perform concurrently with another thread, but you might not need it e.g. if you know your other thread is paused for some other reason.

Comment: @ Tim B i think writing updation code in syn block does not make hashmap "linkDetailsMap" inaccessable from some other class.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But so long as every thread puts their modifications in a sync block then it is fine.

Comment: Actually in my case modification is done by just a single thread but hashmap is getting accessed(read only)  from many differnt thread.what i wanted is make this hashmap inaccessable when the value part of Hashmap entry i.e. Link object is modified.

Comment: one more point hashmap is not getting modified only the value part of Hashmap entry i.e. Link object is modified.value part of hashmap is still have the same link reference.

Comment: That's not what you said in your question. In that case look at the ReentrantReadWriteLock as mentioned by Matthieu.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the hashmap is being modified or not, it's just being used as a convenient lock object. However this is turning into a discussion so I'm out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Semaphores as below.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1); //Have this as singleton instance all with the map.
.....
//before write
semaphore.acquire();
//actual write.
semaphore.release()
.....
//Before read check if semaphore is already acquired as below.
if(semaphore.availablePermits() == 1) {
 //Perform read 
}  else {
 //Wait and read later.
}
```